# Test assertion as a boolean

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm looking for a way to store the result of a test as a boolean. There is any way I can use `pm.response.to.have.body("Example")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
var isExamplePresent = pm.response.text().includes("Example");
```

The `includes()` method checks if the response body contains the string "Example". The result is then stored in the `isExamplePresent` variable as a boolean value.